# Stopped class in html/css

Tags: html, css, class

I am making website in html and css and I have a problem. In my css file I made id "full" which set wooden background after sidebar and it should continue on all page. In my class "picture" I made 80% width white panel - so there should be 80% white background in the middle and 10% edges should be wooden. It works correctly untill my article section, where I added some images of pizzeria. Immediately there is no wooden edges, only white. I don´t understand because my "full" id and "picture" class continue untill end of the body. Could somebody see where is error please?
[Image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud7cc.jpg)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#full {
  background-image: url("http://newallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Dark-Wood-620x387.jpg");
}

.picture {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
}

#pizzaObrazok {
  background-image: url("img/pizzaCompleted.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 210px;
  margin: 0px;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}

ul {
  float: left
}

li {
  display: inline;
  border: 4px solid black;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px 64px;
  background-color: #990000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#imgPizza {
  width: 59%;
  height: 270px;
  padding-left: 190px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

article p {
  font-size: 120%;
  font-family: fantasy;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 160px;
}

#imgPizza2 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 270px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(345deg);
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: 6px solid red;
}

#imgPizza3 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 270px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 390px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  border: 6px solid red;
}

#phone {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-right: 180px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ff4d4d;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="pizzaObrazok">
  </div>
</header>
<div id="full">
  <section id="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="pizza.html">ÚVOD</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FOTO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JEDÁLNY LÍSTOK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">KDE NÁS NÁJDETE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">NÁZORY</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    &nbsp
  </section>
  <div class="picture">
    <img id="imgPizza" src="img/pizzacheese.jpg">
    <aside id="phone">
      <h2>Telefónne číslo:</h2>
      <h2> 0905 741 963</h2>
    </aside>
  </div>
  &nbsp
  <div class="picture">
    <article>
      <p>U nás dostanete najchutnejšiu pizzu z výlučne kvalitných surovín</p>
      <img id="imgPizza2" src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/50289897/pizzeria_otto.0.0.jpg">
      <img id="imgPizza3" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/09/bc/74/79/pizzeria-du-drugstore.jpg">
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would say put the image as a background of the body, and make sure to use the `cover` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your elements  "#imgPizza2" and "#imgPizza3" whit position absolute outside your "#full" wrapper. You can do various things to achive the effect you are looking for but depends of many others things.

I think the simpliest way is to put your [background image in to the body](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvNYxG?editors=1100) and not in the warpper "#full" or [change the postion of your images](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLvbym?editors=1100) among others.

```
body {
  background-image: url("http://newallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Dark-Wood-620x387.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the wood background is 620 x 387, so my first thought is that it is big enough to cover the first section but not the articles. Maybe add `background-repeat: repeat-y;` to your `#full` class and see if the wood border spreads further down the page.